# Fancy indexing python

Tags: python, indexing

I struggle with fancy indexing in python. Say I have a numpy array full of zeros and now I want to fill each row with ones up to a given index.

```
a = np.zeros((3,20))
limits = np.array([5, 10, 15])
```

Intuitively I would like to do something like `a[:,:limits] = 1` but that does not work:

`TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

I don't want to use any loops or list comprehension.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
a[(np.indices(a.shape)[-1].T < limits).T] = 1
```

which gives:

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Awesome thank you very much!

Comment: Just to note, in this particular case, my solution is actually slower (by about 3 times) than just doing a for loop over each row. It might prove more efficient for larger arrays, but it will also consume more memory as it has to allocate an array of indices and a boolean array that are both the same size as `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you put an extra colon symbol in your code.

```py
a[:,limits] = 1
```

will fill 5-th, 10-th and 15-th columns with 1 (using your input data).

Comment: Hej thanks, but this is not want I want to have. I want to fill each row up until the limit with ones. So the result should look like this:
`array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
            [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])`

Comment: Oh, I got it know. I don't know an elegant solution, but this workaround can do the trick:
1) put 1 in zero column in each row
2) put -1 in the first column, that should not been filled with 1
3) take cumulative sum for each row

```python
a[:, 0] = 1
a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), limits] = -1
a = a.cumsum(axis=1)
```